# Linux-Embedded: Nanopi kernel build - Led support - sys/class/leds empty

Tags: embedded-linux

I am building a kernel for nanopi neo air based on nikkov git files for volumio. The build works fine and image is running on the nanopi fine as well. However the green status led is not working and trigger function not available under sys/class/leds (it is empty)

HW: Nanopineo air, Armv7

- .config generated by makefile looks okey:

> CONFIG_NEW_LEDS=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_CLASS=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_GPIO=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGERS=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_TIMER=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_ONESHOT=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_HEARTBEAT=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_CPU=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_GPIO=y
>
> CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_DEFAULT_ON=y

- volumio@volumio:~$ cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin shows that the driver has been built-in prepoerly on the nanopi:

> kernel/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-timer.ko
>
> kernel/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-oneshot.ko
>
> kernel/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-heartbeat.ko
>
> kernel/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-gpio.ko
>
> kernel/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-default-on.ko

- The Dtsi file used has info for LEDS

  leds {
  compatible = "gpio-leds";
  pinctrl-names = "default";
  pinctrl-0 = <&leds_npi>, <&leds_r_npi>;

  ```
        status {
            label = "nanopi:blue:status";
            gpios = <&pio 0 10 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
        };

        pwr {
            label = "nanopi:green:pwr";
            gpios = <&r_pio 0 10 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            default-state = "on";
        };

        pwr_en {
            label = "nanopi:none:pwr_en";
            gpios = <&pio 0 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            default-state = "on";
        };
    };
  ```
- BUT no file can be found under `sys/class/leds` it should normally be there what may explain that the green status LED does not do Heartbeat when kernel starts.

For some reasons these files are not placed properly.

Any idea what is going on here ?

Thanks

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate to add SOLVED to your post title or to edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help.self-answer) for more information. If you don't want to do so, you can either wait for someone else to answer it and accept that answer, or you can delete the question using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now. Suni8 dtsi file provided by Friendlyarm had an issue trying to allocate uart0 and leds to the same pin. Once this resolved all works.